# image classification when a class contains different kind of images

Tags: python

i have to classifiy images into 4 categories food attire misc and dectoration but when i see my data of food class it contains variety of images like it has cakes pics,it has wines bottel it has plates pics and so many other which are related to food but not vary similar so how to classifiy such i use transfer learning but did't get good acc

please to see dataset visit https://www.hackerearth.com/challenges/competitive/hackerearth-deep-learning-challenge-auto-tag-images-gala/machine-learning/auto-tag-images-of-the-gala-9e47fb31/

it is hackearth competion of gala event

Comment: please post some code

Comment: Hi Anish, looks to me like you're asking people to solve your competition challenge, which I am not entirely sure is ethical. You might want to remove this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try training with the small number of class, but covariate shift will be a big issue, and may end up with an unstable model.

You can use unsupervised techniques to add more sub-classes to the model.

First of all, you can compress the image dimensions (with PCA, t-SNE, etc.), then apply k-means clustering to find the probable new classes. Then, assign the appropriate class names to each cluster. You will end up with more classes. Then, you can train your deep learning model with those extra classes to get a more stable model.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
# flatten the X image array

X_embedded = TSNE(n_components=2).fit_transform(X)
X_embedded.shape

# apply, k-means to find suitable clusters

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X_embedded)
kmeans.labels_

# test images
kmeans.predict(X_test)

kmeans.cluster_centers_

# for each cluster center assign a new class
```

Comment: brother model which i have to submit has only 4 class if i have to increase the class what happens to class prediction on 4 class if you can then please see the data it quite freek \